# Prove Stirling's Formula: $n!=\kappa n^{n+1/2}\exp\bigg(-n+\dfrac{\theta(n)}{12n}\bigg)$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Prove Stirling's Formula, i.e.
>
> $n!=\kappa n^{n+1/2}\exp\bigg(-n+\dfrac{\theta(n)}{12n}\bigg),$
>
> where $1-\dfrac{1}{12n+1}\le\theta(n)\le 1$ and $\kappa=\sqrt{2\pi}$.

I tried to do it by induction, but it didn't work. Where did I make a mistake ?

If the equation ist true, then

$\dfrac{\kappa (n+1)^{n+3/2}\exp\bigg(-n-1+\dfrac{\theta(n+1)}{12n+12}\bigg)}{\kappa n^{n+1/2}\exp\bigg(-n+\dfrac{\theta(n)}{12n}\bigg)}=\dfrac{(n+1)!}{n!}=n+1$.

After some steps, I get

$(n+\dfrac{1}{2})(log(n+1)-log(n))=1+\dfrac{\theta(n)}{12n}-\dfrac{\theta(n+1)}{12n+12}$$\quad$$(*)$

then i can estimate the LHS from above and below

$\dfrac{n+1/2}{n+1}<(n+\dfrac{1}{2})(log(n+1)-log(n))<\dfrac{n+1/2}{n}$

but the RHS of $(*)$ doesn't necessarily contain the interval $(\dfrac{n+1/2}{n+1},\dfrac{n+1/2}{n})$

EDIT: The answers given below are a bit too complicated for me, i only ask if my approach is correct or not.

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation

Answer (score 2):

One easy way to get it is to use the [Euler-Maclaurin formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula). For $f(x)$ it gives the asymptotic expansion (it normally *doesn't* converge, but its first terms give an approximation):
$$
    \sum_{1 \le k < a} f(k)
      = \int_1^a f(z) \, \mathrm{d} z
   + \gamma_f
   + B_1 f(a)
   + \sum_{1 \le k \le n}
        \frac{B_{2 k}}{(2 k)!} f^{(2 k - 1)}(a)
   + R_n(f; a)
$$
Here the $B_k$ are [Bernoulli numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number), $\gamma_f$ is a constant, depending on $f$:
$$
    \gamma_f
      = \lim_{b \rightarrow \infty}
    \left(
      \sum_{1 \le k \le b} f(k) - \int_1^b f(z) \, \mathrm{d} z
    \right)
$$
and $R_n$ is a remainder.

Taking $f(x) = \ln x$, by disregarding the sum above and as $B_1 = 1/2$:
$$
\ln n! = \sum_{1 \le k \le n} \ln k 
       \approx \ln n  + \int_1^n \ln z \, \mathrm{d} z + \ln \sigma
    + \frac{1}{2} \ln n 
       = \ln \sigma + n \ln n + \frac{1}{2} \, \ln n - n
$$
Here $\ln \sigma$ is the above constant $\gamma_{\ln}$. To get it's value, start with [Wallis' product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product):
$$
\frac{\pi}{2} = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}
    \frac{1}{2 n + 1} \cdot
      \frac{2^{4 n} \, n!^4}{(2 n)!^2}
$$
Substituting the approximation for the factorial derived above gives $\sigma = \sqrt{2 \pi}$. Pulling all together gives Stirling's approximation:
$$
n! \approx \sqrt{2 \pi n} \, \left( \frac{n}{e} \right)^n
$$
There are many other ways to derive this result.

Answer (score 1):

One first approximation to the Stirling formula can be obtained using Riemann sums of $f(x)=\ln(x)$, i.e.,

$$\ln(n!)=\sum_{k=2}^n\ln(k).$$

Since the anti-derivative is $F(x)=x(\ln x-1)$ and $f$ is monotonically increasing you get

$$f(k)\cdot 1\le F(k+1)-F(k)\le f(k+1)\cdot 1$$

over the interval $[k,k+1]$ and summing up over $[1,n]$ resp. $[2,n+1]$ gives the middle sum both as an upper and lower Riemann sum

$$F(n)-F(1)\le\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)\le F(n+1)-F(2)$$

or

$$n\ln(n/e)+1\le \ln(n!)\le (n+1)\ln((n+1)/e)-2\ln(2/e)$$

or

$$e\left(\frac ne\right)^n\le n!\le \left(\frac e2\right)^2\left(\frac {n+1}e\right)^{n+1}$$

---

Since $f(x)=\ln(x)$ is not only monotone but also concave, the trapezoid rule gives a better lower estimate for the integral. Over $[1,n+1]$ it reads as
$$
\tfrac12 f(1)+\sum_{k=2}^n f(k)+\tfrac12 f(n+1)
\le F(n+1)-F(1)=(n+1)(\ln(n+1)-1)+1
\\~\\
\ln(n!)\le n(\ln(n+1)-1)+\tfrac12\ln(n+1)
$$
or
$$
n!\le \sqrt{n+1}\,\left(\frac{n+1}e\right)^n
=\sqrt{n+1} \left(1+\tfrac1n\right)^n \,\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n
\le e\sqrt{n+1}\,\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n
$$

---

For the exact bound see indeed the wikipedia page.

Comment: How can you estimate the middle part (with sum)